# Calling a function makes my code ridiculousy slow

Tags: c++, performance, function, call

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that given a rectangle and a number of polygons decided by the user, can recognize whether they are inside, outside or intersect the rectangle and provides the number of said polygons.

I coded an algorithm and it works, but I noticed that right after the compilation it takes at least 20seconds to start ( this won't happen if I start it a second, third or any other time ).

Trying to figure out what was slowing my code so much, I noticed that the program runs instantly if I delete the call to the function that determines polygon's position in relation to the rectangle.

I tried to find something wrong but found nothing

Here it is

```
// struct used in the function
struct Polygon
{
    int ** points;
    int vertices;
};
// inside, outside and over are the number of polygons that are inside, outside or intersect the rectangle,
// they're initialized to 0 in the main.
// down_side, up_side are the y_coordinate of the two horizontals sides.
// left_side, right_side are the x_coordinate of the two vertical sides.
void checkPolygons( Polygon * polygon, int & inside, int & outside, int & over, unsigned int polygons, const unsigned int down_side, const unsigned int up_side, const unsigned int left_side, const unsigned int right_side )
{
    for ( unsigned int pol = 0; pol < polygons; ++pol )
    {
        unsigned int insideVertices = 0;
        unsigned int vertices = polygon[ pol ].vertices;

        for ( unsigned int point = 0; point < vertices; ++point )
        {
            unsigned int x_coordinate = polygon[ pol ].points[ point ][ 0 ];
            unsigned int y_coordinate = polygon[ pol ].points[ point ][ 1 ];

            if ( ( x_coordinate <= right_side ) and ( x_coordinate >= left_side ) and ( y_coordinate <= up_side ) and ( y_coordinate >= down_side ) )
            {
                insideVertices++;
            }

        }

        if ( insideVertices == 0 )
            ++outside;
        else if ( insideVertices == vertices ) 
            ++inside;
        else
            ++over;
    }
}
```

Comment: what compiler/os are you using?

Comment: MinGW (gcc) under Windows

Comment: Perhaps codereview.stackexchange.com? `unsigned int x_coordinate = polygon[ pol ].points[ point ][ 0 ];` looks to be killer for the cache.

Comment: I might be wrong, but due to some really weird network related issues the mingw compiled code loads slowly on some windows systems. Try disabling your network adapters and let us know what happens, or try a different compiler/os ... I had this problem and only disabling both the wireless and wired network made the programs load faster.

Comment: I added it because I wanted to make quicker controls on them, otherwise I should have written the if statement as 
if ( ( polygon[ pol ].points[ point ][ 0 ] <= right_side ) and ( polygon[ pol ].points[ point ][ 0 ] >= left_side ) and ( polygon[ pol ].points[ point ][ 1 ] <= up_side ) and ( polygon[ pol ].points[ point ][ 1 ] >= down_side ) ). Shouldn't the first be faster?

Comment: Another possibility is your antivirus checking the newly compiled executable.

Comment: also, how do you insert the code in the first post?

Comment: @Alexey Frunze It was! Thank you... So nothing to worry about.. What options in the 2 i listed in the upper code do you think it's faster?

Comment: That's not part of the original question. And I don't think if you phrase it like this, it will be a good new question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your antivirus activity and configuration. It may be scanning the newly compiled executables for viruses. If that's the case, you may want to exclude the directory where you are compile from virus scanning.

Comment: excellent... when the real life invades the abstract realms programmers dvelve in

Comment: @fritzone Happened to me several times. :)